# Create a metric in workspace for the rate at which any page is the previous page to a specific page?

Tags: adobe-analytics

Our site has several error page including a catch-all error page for errors that we cannot identify. I am trying to create a metric in workspace that will give me the rate at which any page is the previous page to the catch-all error page.

This is what I tried (not working):

```
((page=catch-all AND previous page exists)[Unique visitors])/(Page exists[Unique Visitors]
```

It gives me 99% on the error page itself and 0% for every other page.

I previously had another formula working correctly for specified pages like this:

```
((page=catch-all AND previous page=specific page)[Unique visitors])/(page=specific page[Unique Visitors]
```

This would give the error rate of a specific page. How do I create a metric that can sub in any page in workspace?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to obtain this data is to fire a custom event whenever an error message is shown. From there, you can calculate error rate by taking the total number of errors and dividing it by the total number of page views for each given page.